# Unable to get files from temp folder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file-io, filesystems

I'm creating picture browser app similar to Photo app on iPhone. I download pictures from web storing them on TEMP folder

```
NSString *uniquePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: filename];
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(localImage, 100) writeToFile:uniquePath atomically:YES];
```

and later retrieving to display them on UIImage View.

```
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: uniquePath])
{
  UIImage* localImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: uniquePath]; 
}
```

Everything work well until I manually delete the items in folder

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:NSTemporaryDirectory() error:&errorInfo];
```

Once above code is executed, I'm no longer able to store or retrieve images, but control flow shows that images exist in temp folder...
Can anyone identify what would be the problem ?

PS: Images are ~25Kb in size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:NSTemporaryDirectory() error:&errorInfo];
```

You are removing the temp directory instead of temp files. `NSTemporaryDirectory` does NOT create directory if it doesn't exist.